# `git stash` during a merge conflict

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-stash, merge-conflict-resolution

We've done something bad.

We ran `git stash save` during a merge conflict, and now we can't restore our work.

Things we've tried:

```
git pull -Xours origin master
git stash apply --index
```

And:

```
 git pull origin master
 git stash save --keep-index "merge conflicts"
 git stash apply stash@{1}
```

Please help!

Comment: Did you actually do anything significant? (Do you actually need to restore the stashed changes?) Can you just reset away the attempted merge, and do it over again?

Comment: Yes and no, respectively. The changes consist of more than one day of merge conflict resolution.

Comment: @bukzor: If you need more then one day for merge conflict resolution it might be time to rethink your policies regarding branch handling and work distribution (or merge frequency). Such lengthy merge resolutions are afterall a nice source of hard to find bugs due to the amount of changes done in one commit

Comment: What error did you get? Why not a simple 'git stash apply'?

Comment: @inger: Since `stash save` clears the index and `stash apply` doesn't modify it, you end up with regular unstaged changes, not a merge. I want to apply those changes during merge, but can't see how.

Comment: Have you tried using a gui to look at your repo? gitx shows stashes that sometimes are hard to find on the cli. Might help.

Answer (score 35):

The issue seems to be that `git stash` doesn't save a reference to the branch you were trying to merge in. During a merge, this is stored in a ref named `MERGE_HEAD`.

To fix it and get back to your previous state, you need to find the revision (let's pretend it's d7a9884a380f81b2fbf002442ee9c9eaf34ff68d) you were trying to merge in, and set MERGE_HEAD to it after you apply the stash.

Then you can apply the stash (with --index to re-stage everything that was staged before), and set your `MERGE_HEAD`:

```
git stash apply --index
git update-ref MERGE_HEAD d7a9884a380f81b2fbf002442ee9c9eaf34ff68d
```

Comment: While the above seems true to me, I am not entirely confident that just setting MERGE_HEAD and unstashing is enough to restore the merge status. I would steer away from using git stash during conflicts, if possible.

Comment: Had same issue, and tried your solution. It complained that `.git/MERGE_MSG` didn't exist, I created that file with a custom merge message and then I committed after. I was worried that I would be marked as the author of all the changes in the merge, but it seems to have worked out as it should. Other authors properly creditted. Thanks :)

Comment: I had a stash and a pop in my pre-commit hook which was deleting .git/MERGE_HEAD causing a file not found error when trying to commit a merge. It would commit the second time I tried but it wouldn't actually be 'merged'.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same thing today, and took a different approach (after trial and error) to get back to the state just prior to stashing so I could continue resolving conflicts and complete the merge.

First, after unstashing the partial merge in the destination branch, I captured a list of the files with remaining conflicts (text file or editor tab).  This is just the list of unstaged files after unstashing, as the files with conflicts already resolved would have been staged prior to stashing.

```
$ git status
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   myproject/src/main/java/com/acme/package3/Class3.java
#   modified:   myproject/src/main/java/com/acme/package3/Class4.java
#
```

Next, I created a patch and reset the branch back to the pre-merge state:

```
$ git diff HEAD > ~/merge-with-resolved-conflicts.patch
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Then I created a temporary branch (derived from the merge destination branch), and applied the patch:

```
$ git checkout -b my-temp-branch
$ git apply ~/merge-with-resolved-conflicts.patch
$ git commit -a -m "Merge with resolved conflicts"
```

So the HEAD of my-temp-branch now contains everything that was merged, including files with conflicts resolved, and files with remaining conflicts.

Then I switched back to original branch, merged again, and looked at the git status

```
$ git checkout my-branch
$ git merge other-branch
$ git status
```

The status shows the full list of files with conflicts:

```
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      myproject/src/main/java/com/acme/package1/Class1.java
#   both modified:      myproject/src/main/java/com/acme/package2/Class2.java
#   both modified:      myproject/src/main/java/com/acme/package3/Class3.java
#   both modified:      myproject/src/main/java/com/acme/package3/Class4.java
#
```

Now I needed to compare these two lists of files.  Any files in the second list but not the first had already been resolved (in this example, Class1.java and Class2.java).  So for each of those files, I pulled in the version with conflicts resolved from the temporary branch (like cherry-pick, but for individual files rather than an entire commit):

```
$ git checkout my-temp-branch myproject/src/main/java/com/acme/package1/Class1.java
$ git checkout my-temp-branch myproject/src/main/java/com/acme/package2/Class2.java
```

Having done this, I was back to the state before the stash, so I could resume resolving the remaining conflicts and commit the merge.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in a conflicted state ( index and working directory), you will not be able to do `git stash`  - it will give an error sating unmerged entries.

Make sure that you have really done a stash. See output of `git status` and `git stash show`

Comment: Prior to `git stash`, I have resolved the conflicts and proceed to use `git add`.  It was after I have `git add` my resolutions,  I made further edits and then did a `git stash save msg`.  So that did succeed.

Comment: @bukzor actually, I just tested this out with msysgit 1.8.3 on Windows 7. If the file is left conflicted (i.e. no attempt to resolve the merge conflict has been made), then `git stash save` does indeed abort, without stashing the conflicted file. So ***this is actually correct, it is not false***.

Answer (score 1):

You've resolved all your conflicts and then you `git stash`. This reset your working tree to pre-merge stage and puts all the resolutions into a stash.

So, all you need to do is redo the merge and then `checkout` all the contents (`-- .`) of the stash to the working tree. NB, run this in the root of your repository.

```bash
git merge conflict-branch
cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
git checkout stash@{0} -- .
git commit
```

ps, you can use `git worktree add` instead of `git stash` during a merge.

Answer (score 0):

Given your last comment : you can use

```
git stash megre --no-commit <branch>
```

to put the index in a "merge" state without committing the changes

then modify it with what you want :

if you have already worked out your merge in the stash :

```
git reset #to remove the "conflicts" flags
git checkout <initial commit> -- ./ #to revert everything to the previous working state,
git stash apply   #apply your changes
```

and once everything is in the desired state, `git commit`

---

About [bukzor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/146821/bukzor)'s comment : there is actually a big difference between `git checkout <tree-ish>` and `git checkout <tree-ish> -- <files>`.

From the [reference](http://git-scm.com/docs) on [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) :

- `git checkout <branch>` : This form switches branches by updating the index, working tree, and HEAD to reflect the specified branch or commit.
- `git checkout [-p|--patch] <tree-ish> -- <pathspec>` : When <paths> or --patch are given, git checkout does not switch branches. It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named <tree-ish> (most often a commit).

`git checkout <initial commit>` would indeed discard the merge informations.

`git checkout <initial commit> -- ./` (note the extra `-- ./`), on the other hand, will keep the merge information, and revert every tracked file to its state in `<initial commit>`.

Comment: `git checkout` will remove the merging state, won't it? I'll end up with a normal commit that dups all the changes in master.

Comment: `git stash apply` also clears the merge state, explicitly setting the MERGE_HEAD ref as suggested in Evan's answer did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

My solution to get out of this (git stash pop during a merge conflict) was:

- create and checkout a new (local) branch *mytemporarybranch*

  > git branch mytemporarybranch && git checkout mytemporarybranch
- commit into this *mytemporarybranch*

  > git commit -m "my messy merge and squash"
- checkout *myoriginalbranch*

  > git checkout myoriginalbranch
- merge correctly (no squash pop/apply this time!)
- **squash** merge the *mytemporarybranch* onto the *myoriginal* branch

  > git merge --squash mytemporarybranch