# Git: switch branches mid-merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I just spent the last few hours resolving merge conflicts that resulted from merging `big-feature-branch-B` into `big-feature-branch-A`. I am finally finished and all my resolutions are staged and ready to be committed. However, the process where I work is to:

1. Create a branch off of `big-feature-branch-A` (I'll call this branch `AB-merge-branch`)
2. Merge `big-feature-branch-B` into `AB-merge-branch`
3. Create a PR for to merge `AB-merge-branch` into `big-feature-branch-A`, so that the resolutions can go through code review.

By the time I was most of the way through resolving merge conflicts, I realized that I was resolving them in `big-feature-branch-A` rather than a merge branch.

My question is, how can I safely change branches before committing my changes?

I am sure the answer is simple, and normally I would just stash my changes, switch branches, then pop my changes. However, I have never done this in the midst of a merge, and I am very skittish about just "trying it" in this case, because I don't want to risk having to resolve all those conflicts again, and I am not super confident with my git-fu. I have also read horror stories like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9009354/3642398) (but maybe my case is different, because I have already resolved all conflicts, and all changes are staged?), and don't feel like experimenting in this case. Thank you!

Comment: For reference, `git stash` refuses to work mid-merge. (Somewhat reasonable, as the context is more than a set of file-deltas). Still it does seem this is a shortcoming in git that you can't "pause" a merge to switch branches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't (switch branches ... well, sort of, although you can, sort of, but it's not advisable—it involves monkeying directly with the innards of Git):

```
$ git checkout -b newbr
foo.txt: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

Your index is in this special "merging" state and therefore you cannot stash either.  Fortunately, there is no need to do so.  (If you resolve everything and then run `git checkout -b newbr` and commit, you get a non-merge commit.  You can use this, but let's not do it that way.)

What you should do is go ahead and finish the merge: this gives you the merge *result* you want. You can then re-start the merge in the *branch* you want, and grab the result you just committed as the *result* you want, *if that's even necessary*.  You then discard the original merge commit entirely (if necessary).  (This is also what you need to do if you accidentally wrecked the merge with a successful `git checkout -b` as almost shown above.)

In some cases—including *your* case—the original merge's parent links are the ones you wanted, and it's just a matter of re-*labeling* the merge.

I'll show the recipe first, but then explain *why* it works:

```
... finish merging ...
$ git commit                         # commit the merge
$ git checkout -b AB-merge-branch    # create the merge branch
$ git checkout big-feature-branch-A  # get back to other branch
$ git reset --hard HEAD^             # take the merge off of it
```

#### Why this is an answer (there are multiple ways so I won't say *the* answer)

Let's draw your setup as it was when you first started to merge:

```
       o--...--o--o   <-- big-feature-branch-A (HEAD)
      /
...--*
      \
       o--...--o--o   <-- big-feature-branch-B
```

That is, you were, as `git status` would put it, "on branch big-feature-branch-A" and all was well.  Each `o` represents a commit (and I marked the merge base, for the merge, with an asterisk).

You then *intended* to run `git checkout -b AB-merge-branch`.  If you *had* done that, the picture would look like this:

```
    o--...--o--o   <-- big-feature-branch-A, AB-merge-branch (HEAD)
   /
--*
   \
    o--...--o--o   <-- big-feature-branch-B
```

You ran `git merge`, which failed with conflicts.  You resolved (most of) the conflicts (you must resolve them all before you proceed).  When you finally commit, you will get a new merge commit, and that will move the *current* branch (the one remembered by `HEAD`):

```
    o--...--o--o   <-- big-feature-branch-A
   /            \
--*              M   <-- AB-merge-branch (HEAD)
   \            /
    o--...--o--o   <-- big-feature-branch-B
```

Not shown here (because it is too hard to show) is that the *first* parent of the new merge `M` is the rightmost (latest) upper row commit, and the second is the lower.  (This first vs second stuff matters later, if at all, when someone wants to follow the "main" branch vs "side features that were merged in": the main branch is always the first parent, by definition.)

You forgot to create a new branch *name*, so what happens now, instead, is this:

```
    o--...--o--o
   /            \
--*              M   <-- big-feature-branch-A (HEAD)
   \            /
    o--...--o--o   <-- big-feature-branch-B
```

The first parent is *still* the top-and-right-most commit, the second parent is still the bottom such commit.  The new merge commit `M` is *exactly the same*.  It's just that the *label* that moved, to point to new merge `M`, is `big-feature-branch-A` (the one that is HEAD), and not the nonexistent `AB-merge-branch` (which obviously isn't HEAD).

So all you have to do now is *create* the labeling you wanted.  Anything that makes the new branch name `AB-merge-branch`, pointing to `M`, suffices for that part.  You can use `git checkout -b AB-merge-branch` or `git branch AB-merge-branch` to do that.

If you do use `git checkout -b` you now have to get *back* to `big-feature-branch-A` to fix it up using `git reset` (there are other commands you could use, but I'm sticking with `reset` here).  If you use `git branch` to create the new branch, your *current* branch is undisturbed: you are still on `big-feature-branch-A`.

In any case, you want this `big-feature-branch-A` branch name to move back one step, to the first parent of `M`, as if it had never moved forward to `M` in the first place.  So you get back on (or stay on) this branch.  Once you're on this branch, you can use `git reset --hard HEAD^` to achieve this moving-back-one-step.  `HEAD^` means "find the first parent of `HEAD`", which—if `HEAD` names commit `M` (it does)—means the rightmost upper row commit, which is where you want the branch to point.  The `git reset` command does this re-pointing of the branch, and also re-sets your index and work-tree (so that everything is cleanly on the new commit).

Comment: Same except I don't need to checkout big-feature-branch-A back.

Comment: Excellent and enlightening answer!  +1 for diagrams too :D

Comment: In rereading this question, I found git doesn't behave this way for me. If I have resolved all conflicts, then `git checkout -b newbr` **completes successfully**, casually discarding the in-progress merge metadata. `git switch -c`, on the other hand, refuses.

Is this an error in your answer (in that you assume there are unresolved conflicts, but there may not be), or has there been a behavior change in git?

Answer (score 4):

First, simply finish your merge and commit. That way, you won't lose anything.
This is a local operation and won't be seen by anybody else.

From that commit, you can create your branch AB-merge-branch

```
 git checkout -b AB-merge-branch
```

And you can reset your previous `big-feature-branch-A` to its first parent commit.

```
 git branch --force big-feature-branch-A big-feature-branch-A^1
```

Answer (score 0):

Correcting/complementing @torek's answer slightly, I find that if I switch branches to commit my conflict-resolved merge on a new branch with `git checkout -b AB-merge-branch`, **the branch change succeeds**, but as a side-effect of the branch change, **I also lose the merging state**.

When I commit, I don't get a merge-driven commit message proposal, and the resulting commit only has one parent commit.

To get from this "accidentally created a new independent commit" state to where I want to be, without of course needing to re-resolve the conflicts I already resolved, and assuming I created this "non-merge commit" on `AB-merge-branch`, I find I need to do something like the following:

```bash
git switch -c AB-merge-branch-corrected AB-merge-branch~1
git merge -s ours --no-commit big-feature-branch-B
git restore --worktree --staged --source AB-merge-branch -- .
git commit # I get the expected merge message prompt
git switch AB-merge-branch
git reset AB-merge-branch-corrected
git branch -d AB-merge-branch-corrected
```

Generally speaking, the simplest advice is to *create the new branch before you start merging*, exactly as the process at your work stipulates.

If you *haven't switched branches yet*, then @torek's advice above is the right/simplest one.