# How to undo git pull from master branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I wanted to make my branch up to date and mistakenly pulled from master branch using " git pull origin master " and now i have some 700 pending changes to commit.
How do i undo this and not mess up anything in here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `git merge --abort`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Abort a Git Merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048982/abort-a-git-merge)

Comment: my 2 cents, never use `git pull`, use `git fetch` and merge or rebase your job according to what you need

Comment: @Ôrel seems unnecessary, why?

Comment: You don't know what will happen doing `git pull` , doing `git fetch` you can check what happens on the remote before updating your current branch. This is more robust and avoid surpise

Comment: @Ôrel what do you mean you don't know?

Comment: `git fetch` allows you to sync the remote state, and see the gap between your branch and the remote one. Doing `git pull` this will fetch and apply the modification

Comment: @Ôrel I suggest that's an unnecessary fear/restriction - there's no fundamental problem using `git pull` - but if your workflow works for you of course that's no problem. If you can be confident it's trivial to fix or establish previous state _if_ there is a problem after `git pull`(which would be exactly the same problem after rebasing/merging), there's no reason to shy away from using it. Just comes down to being familiar with a tool and using it appropriately :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `git stash` and that took me back to the clean working directory.
Thank you for all your responses!

Comment: Be careful stashing during a merge. [You may have trouble applying it again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009354/git-stash-during-a-merge-conflict). Also I don't think stashing aborts the merge

Answer (score 0):

To undo the merge, you could use `git reset --hard`. This will reset the local repository to a previous state.

Be aware though that this will remove all uncommitted changes, potentially leading to a loss of work:

Alternatively, you can reset to a particular point in time, such as:

```
git reset --hard master@{"10 minutes ago"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard master@{"[time]"}
```

and be sure to replace time since the last pull
for detailed answer check this

[Undo git pull, how to bring repos to old state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223354/undo-git-pull-how-to-bring-repos-to-old-state)