# Resuming merge conflict resolution in a remote repository

Tags: git, repository, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Following on from [GitHub subtree merge requests](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/17207), I've been pondering whether a merge conflict that arises during a(n automated) `git subtree pull` could easily be "stored" somewhere in order that it can later be "resumed" on a different (manual) copy of the repo.

From [`git stash` during a merge conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12520322), I gather that a merge conflict can (with a little tweaking) be stashed and resumed in the same repo; and from [How can I share a git stash?](https://superuser.com/a/409290), I gather that a stash can be shared with a remote repo as a regular commit... but the former requires `git stash pop`'s `--index` flag in order to restore an index state that differs from that of the working set, whereas the latter would entail a `git checkout` of the remote stash's ref that results in an index that is aligned with the working set.  I'm not even sure whether pushing a stash as a regular ref would retain such distinct information for the two data structures?

Is there any way that merge conflict resolution can be resumed in another/remote copy of the repo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing rerere cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566023/sharing-rerere-cache)

Comment: @Ôrel: Honestly, I'm not sure.  Nothing in that suggests that an unresolved merge conflict can be suspended in one repo and continued in another, but I'll have a play and report back.